# Table of relative entropies of common distributions?

Tags: references, entropy, information-theory, kullback-leibler

Does anyone know where I can find a reference table of relative entropies between common distributions? Despite spending some effort searching, I can't seem to locate one.

Comment: Here is [a list of some related posts](https://www.google.com/search?q=list+of+relative+entropies+between+distributions+cross+validated+site:stats.stackexchange.com&client=ubuntu&hs=sMH&channel=fs&sxsrf=AOaemvJudohgDRRYgA6RrwSs7wNdJgvAgQ:1634823455404&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiindH6z9vzAhXAIbkGHTGLBx4QrQIoBHoECAUQBQ&biw=1235&bih=645&dpr=1.5)